# Issues With hitTestObject in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, action

Im just trying to loop through the two arrays the bullet and enemies array then i perform the hitTestObject on both but it doesnt seem to work until the enemy gets really close to the player or bullet. 
here is my code sorry that my code is sloppy `

```
// ******* IMPORTS *****
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

//*****VARIABLES****

var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var shootDown:Boolean = false;

var ySpeed:int = 0;
var xSpeed:int = 0;

var scrollX:int = 0;
var scrollY:int = 0;

var speedConstant:int = 5;

var friction:Number = 0.6;

var level:Number = 1;

var bullets:Array;
var container_mc:MovieClip; 
var enemies:Array;
var tempEnemy:MovieClip;


// BUTTON EVENTS EITHER CLICKED OR NOT

left_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveLeft);
right_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveRight);
up_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveUp);
shoot_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, shootPressed);

left_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, leftUp);
right_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, rightUp);
up_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, upUp);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, makeEnemies);



player.gotoAndStop('still');


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);

function onenter(e:Event):void{
    if (rightPressed == true && leftPressed == false){
        player.x += 8;
        player.scaleX = 1;
        player.gotoAndStop("walking");
        cloud.x -= 8;


    } else if (leftPressed == true && rightPressed == false){
        player.x -= 8;
        player.scaleX = -1;
        player.gotoAndStop('walking');
        cloud.x += 8;

   } else if(upPressed == true && leftPressed == false && rightPressed == false){


       }
        else{  
        rightPressed = false;
        leftPressed = false;
        player.gotoAndStop('still')}

}
// **** MOVEMENT CONTROLS *********



function shootPressed(e:MouseEvent):void{
    shootDown = true;
    if(shootDown == true){
        fireBullet();
        testCollisions();
        }

    }


function fireBullet():void
{
    var playerDirection:String;
    if(player.scaleX < 0){
        playerDirection = "left";
    } else if(player.scaleX > 0){
        playerDirection = "right";
    }
    var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(player.x, player.y, playerDirection);
    bullets = new Array();
    bullet.y = 288;
    stage.addChild(bullet);
    bullets.push(bullet);
    trace(bullets);

}

// BUTTON FUNCTIONS

function moveLeft(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN){
    leftPressed = true;
    }else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP) {
        leftPressed = false;
        }

}
function moveRight(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN){
    rightPressed = true;
    }else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP){
        rightPressed = false;
        }

}
function moveUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN){
        upPressed = true;
        } else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP) {
            upPressed = false;
            }

}



function leftUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    leftPressed = false;
}
function rightUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    rightPressed = false;
}
function upUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    upPressed = false;
}




enemies = new Array();

//Call this function for how many enemies you want to make...
function makeEnemies(e:Event):void
{
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60);
if (chance <= 2){

    //Make sure a Library item linkage is set to Enemy...
    tempEnemy = new enemy();
    tempEnemy.speed = 80;
    tempEnemy.x = Math.round(Math.random() * stage.stageWidth) * -10;
    addChild(tempEnemy);
    enemies.push(tempEnemy);
    moveEnemies();
    }
}


function moveEnemies():void
{
    var tempEnemy:MovieClip;
    for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempEnemy = enemies[i];
        tempEnemy.x += tempEnemy.speed;
        tempEnemy.y = 285;
    }
}



//Check for collisions between an enemies array and a Lasers array
function testCollisions():void
{

    var tempEnemy:MovieClip;
    var tempLaser:MovieClip;

    Enemy:for (var i:int=enemies.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        tempEnemy = enemies[i];
        for (var j:int=bullets.length-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            tempLaser = bullets[j];
            if (tempLaser.hitTestObject(tempEnemy))
            {
                removeChild(tempEnemy);
                trace("BULLET HIT");
                break Enemy;
            } else if(tempEnemy.hitTestObject(player)){
                removeChild(tempEnemy);
                trace("HIT PLAYER");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: I realized my error that I called the function when shootPressed was called but now i changed it to run every frame and did the function passed a parameter of e:Event and get the error --- TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Game_fla::MainTimeline/testCollisions()[Game_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:199]-----------How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you're only checking for collisions when the shoot button is pressed, which would explain why it's not happening quickly. I suspect you want to run `testCollisions` every frame instead:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, testCollisions);
```

Comment: yes I was really frustrated and thought about it and i wa calling it when shoot pressed and that solved it thank you...Now the problem is i get a the error TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Game_fla::MainTimeline/testCollisions()[Game_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:199]

Comment: I get this error maybe because the parameter of the testcollision function is e:Event?? maybe

Comment: Oh, yes, that's probably it, does that fix it?

Comment: Now that I look at it, it's probably due to your `bullets` array not being initialized at first. I'd change line 28 to `var bullets:Array = new Array();` and then decide whether you want to recreate it each time in `fireBullet()`.

Comment: Yes, that solve it thank you. Do you mind if I could link you to another question to see if you could help me, I dont know my way around so i dont know how to post my code again other than starting a new question.

Comment: Please do, I think the site encourages separate questions anyway.

Comment: okay I explain my issue there but anyways I try to only spawn 10 zombies in the first level and spawn them off the stage and have them move in to the center but I dont how how to do that the problem might be in the makeEnemies where I set tempEnemy.x =

Comment: anyways here is my new question if you would take the time to help I would greatly appreciate.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583584/how-do-i-spawn-enemy-at-either-the-far-left-or-the-far-right-of-the-stage-and-ha

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594810/using-the-enter-frame-event-listener-in-actionscript-3