# How Do I spawn Enemy at either the far left or the far right of the stage and have them move in to the center?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, game-development

First I get This Error

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at Game_fla::MainTimeline/testCollisions()[Game_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:205]
```

and here is my code

```
  // ******* IMPORTS *****
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

//*****VARIABLES****

var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var shootDown:Boolean = false;

var ySpeed:int = 0;
var xSpeed:int = 0;

var scrollX:int = 0;
var scrollY:int = 0;

var speedConstant:int = 5;

var friction:Number = 0.6;

var level:Number = 1;

var bullets:Array = new Array();
var container_mc:MovieClip; 
var enemies:Array;
var tempEnemy:MovieClip;


// BUTTON EVENTS EITHER CLICKED OR NOT

left_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveLeft);
right_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveRight);
up_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveUp);
shoot_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, shootPressed);

left_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, leftUp);
right_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, rightUp);
up_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, upUp);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, makeEnemies);



player.gotoAndStop('still');


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);

function onenter(e:Event):void{
    if (rightPressed == true && leftPressed == false){
        player.x += 8;
        player.scaleX = 1;
        player.gotoAndStop("walking");
        cloud.x -= 8;


    } else if (leftPressed == true && rightPressed == false){
        player.x -= 8;
        player.scaleX = -1;
        player.gotoAndStop('walking');
        cloud.x += 8;

   } else if(upPressed == true && leftPressed == false && rightPressed == false){


       }
        else{  
        rightPressed = false;
        leftPressed = false;
        player.gotoAndStop('still')}

}
// **** MOVEMENT CONTROLS *********



function shootPressed(e:MouseEvent):void{
    shootDown = true;
    if(shootDown == true){
        fireBullet();
        }

    }


function fireBullet():void
{
    var playerDirection:String;
    if(player.scaleX < 0){
        playerDirection = "left";
    } else if(player.scaleX > 0){
        playerDirection = "right";
    }
    var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(player.x, player.y, playerDirection);
    //bullets = new Array();
    bullet.y = player.y + 8;
    stage.addChild(bullet);
    bullets.push(bullet);
    trace(bullets);

}

// BUTTON FUNCTIONS

function moveLeft(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN){
    leftPressed = true;
    }else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP) {
        leftPressed = false;
        }

}
function moveRight(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN){
    rightPressed = true;
    }else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP){
        rightPressed = false;
        }

}
function moveUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN){
        upPressed = true;
        } else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP) {
            upPressed = false;
            }

}



function leftUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    leftPressed = false;
}
function rightUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    rightPressed = false;
}
function upUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    upPressed = false;
}




enemies = new Array();

//Call this function for how many enemies you want to make...
function makeEnemies(e:Event):void
{
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60);
if (chance <= 2){

    //Make sure a Library item linkage is set to Enemy...
    tempEnemy = new enemy();
    tempEnemy.speed = 80;
    tempEnemy.x = Math.round(Math.random() * stage.stageWidth) * -10;
    addChild(tempEnemy);
    enemies.push(tempEnemy);
    moveEnemies();
    }
}


function moveEnemies():void
{
    var tempEnemy:MovieClip;
    for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempEnemy = enemies[i];
        tempEnemy.x += tempEnemy.speed;
        tempEnemy.y = 285;
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, testCollisions);

//Check for collisions between an enemies array and a Lasers array
function testCollisions(e:Event):void
{

    var tempEnemy:MovieClip;
    var tempLaser:MovieClip;

    for (var i:int=enemies.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        tempEnemy = enemies[i];
        for (var j:int=bullets.length-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            tempLaser = bullets[j];
            if (tempLaser.hitTestObject(tempEnemy))
            {
                removeChild(tempEnemy);
                removeChild(tempLaser);
                trace("BULLET HIT");
                stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, testCollisions);



            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I Understand that I need to reference the parent whenever I `removeChild` in the `testCollision` function but I dont know where.

Also I want the zombies to spawn out of the stage and move in towards the center at a smooth speed with the code I have they just seem to spawn sort of rearly and always to the left of the stage. So I would need to spawn them off the stage and have them move in to the center and change their ScaleX position to change their dirention but I dont know how to do that Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can fix the error you listed by changing `removeChild(tempLaser)` to `stage.removeChild(tempLaser)` since the stage is where you added your bullets, so that's where you need to remove them from.

I'll give you a hint on the zombie movement, but you'll probably want to find a programming forum/friend/professor to help with general code design questions like this. In `moveEnemies`, you'll need to decide whether the zombie should move left/right (based on whether their x position is larger or smaller than the player's), and whether they should move up/down (based on whether their y position is larger or smaller than the player's).

For example, if their x position is larger than the player's, you would do `tempEnemy.x -= tempEnemy.speed`, and if smaller, you would do `tempEnemy.x += tempEnemy.speed`. But as I said, this site isn't really made for these types of design questions.

Comment: Oh ok thank you you have helped me a lot sorry if I asked too much. I got the movement working but the stage.removeChild(tempLaser) still doesnt work.

Comment: Hmm, is it still the same error message? And I was just guessing on the line, does the line number it mentions in the error refer to the removeChild(tempLaser) line?

Comment: its  --------- ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at Game_fla::MainTimeline/testCollisions()[Game_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:205]

Comment: Ok, can you tell which line is #205? In the code in your question, that refers to the `trace("BULLET HIT")` line, which can't be it.

Comment: 205 is removeChild(tempEnemy)

Comment: i deleted the last stage.addEventListener line that was my mistake but it didnt solve it.

Comment: You can try using stage.addChild (both when you add bullets and enemies), and also using stage.removeChild (both for the bullets and enemies).